# CakePHP form builder drop down not preserving french accents

Tags: cakephp, character-encoding, special-characters

The label shows up correctly, but for some reason the options in the drop down menu do not.

```
echo $form->input('job_category', array('label'=>'Emploi Cat&eacute;gorie',
        'options'=>array('Activit&eacute;s commerciales g&eacute;n&eacute;rales')
    ));
```

it produces the following HTML:

```
<option value="0">Activit&amp;eacute;s commerciales g&amp;eacute;n&amp;eacute;rales</option>
```

should be:

```
Activités commerciales générales
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to use character entity references, I believe adding `'escape' => false` to the input array should do it.

But the real answer is: don't use character entity references at all. Make sure the HTML page uses UTF-8 and the code is saved as UTF-8, and you can write accented characters normally in the code.

Comment: thanks! I know it should be in UTF-8, but the app just isnt and this is just a quick fix I had to make for a french version of the site.

Comment: You are a life saviour.. :) VU

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do this?

```
echo $form->input('job_category', array('label'=>'Emploi Catégorie',
        'options'=>array('Activités commerciales générales')
    ));
```

Comment: and make sure you are using utf8 everywhere! thats all there is to it. no &... stuff

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me using spanish accents You need to put the escape option to false like this so cake doesn't escape the special characters

```
echo $form->input('job_category', array('label'=>'Emploi Cat&eacute;gorie',
        'options'=>array('Activit&eacute;s commerciales g&eacute;n&eacute;rales'),
        'escape' => false
    ));
```